# How can I unit test code that contain Task.Delay?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, task-parallel-library, async-await, system.reactive

How can I unit test component that has an await Task.Delay without really having to wait for it.

For example,

```
public void Retry()
{
    // doSomething();
    if(fail)
       await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

I need to test the failure branch but I do not want my test to wait for 5 seconds.

Is there anything like [rx virtual time-based scheduling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/06/14/testing-rx-queries-using-virtual-time-scheduling.aspx) available in task parallel library?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A timer is just another form of external dependency.  The only difference is that it depends on the clock instead of a database.  And like any other external dependency, it makes testing hard; the answer, therefore, is to improve the design until it's easy to test.

Following the Dependency Injection principle suggests that you should pass the timer in on the object's constructor, which enables you to inject a test stub instead of relying on a real timer.

Note how this can improve your design.  In many cases, the timeout period varies based on who's calling.  This moves the responsibility for establishing the timeout period to the layer of your application that's waiting on it.  That is the layer that should understand how long it's willing to wait.

Answer (score 6):

**1) Define your own implementation of Task.Delay.**

```
public static class TaskEx
{
    private static bool _shouldSkipDelays;

    public static Task Delay(TimeSpan delay)
    {
        return _shouldSkipDelays ? Task.FromResult(0) : Task.Delay(delay);
    }

    public static IDisposable SkipDelays()
    {
        return new SkipDelaysHandle();
    }

    private class SkipDelaysHandle : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly bool _previousState;

        public SkipDelaysHandle()
        {
            _previousState = _shouldSkipDelays;
            _shouldSkipDelays = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _shouldSkipDelays = _previousState;
        }
    }
}
```

**2) Use TaskEx.Delay instead of Task.Delay everywhere in your code.**

**3) In your tests use TaskEx.SkipDelays:**

```
[Test]
public async Task MyTest()
{
    using (TaskEx.SkipDelays())
    {
        // your code that will ignore delays
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best option, but with a possible better implementation. If you use Rx, you can also implement this class using IScheduler.Schedule(Timespan). This would allow you to use the Rx test scheduler to actually test timeouts if you need to. And their implementations are basically the same.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there anything like rx virtual time-based scheduling available in task parallel library?

No, there is not. Your options are to either define a "timer service" that you can implement with a test stub, or using Microsoft Fakes to intercept the call to `Task.Delay`. I prefer the latter, but it is only an option on VS Ultimate.

Comment: Coul you provide some more detail on how the latter option can be done?

Comment: I haven't written a blog post on it yet, but [here's some code](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Presentations/tree/ba85a29179091e86743ba0f45c01a1d93fb43f4b/Async%20Unit%20Testing/Demos/Timing)

Comment: how did you add the reference to mscorlib.dll so you could create the fake?

Comment: @Choco: The reference to mscorlib is added automatically.

Comment: @StephenCleary does this (Fakes) work with .Net Core? or is there a new way to achieve the same?

Comment: @nbilal: I am not sure if Fakes works with netcore or not. I recommend the Rx approach anyway.

Comment: @StephenCleary what do you mean by the "Rx approach"? I am testing code that uses Task.Delay internally (retry library) and would like to advance time so that my tests don't take long to run. The code using Task.Delay lives in a library so I can't make it testable using IoC.

Comment: The Rx approach is injecting a scheduler that defines "time". If `Task.Delay` is hard-coded and Fakes doesn't work, then you could try JustMock (which claims to support netcore) or TypeMock (not sure if it supports netcore).

Comment: Ok thanks. TypeMock seems to have a way of mocking static calls but it looks pretty hacky and I'd rather have slow tests over unreadable tests :)

Answer (score 5):

Based on alexey anwser to create a wrapper for Task.Delay, here is how to create a Task.Delay that uses Reactive Extensions' IScheduler, so you can use virtual time to test for delays:

```cs
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static class TaskEx
{
    public static Task Delay(int millisecondsDelay, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        #if TEST
        return Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisecondsDelay), AppContext.DefaultScheduler).ToTask(cancellationToken);
        #else
        return Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay, cancellationToken);
        #endif
    }
}
```

This uses compilation symbols to completely avoid Rx if you are not unit testing.

AppContext is just a context object that has reference to your schedulers. In your tests, you can set `AppContext.DefaultScheduler = testScheduler` and the delay will be caused by the virtual time scheduler.

There is caveat though. The TestScheduler is synchronous, so you cannot start a task and use TaskEx.Delay inside, because the scheduler will advance before the task is scheduled.

```cs
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
AppContext.DefaultScheduler = scheduler;

Task.Run(async () => {
    await TaskEx.Delay(100);
    Console.Write("Done");
});

/// this won't work, Task.Delay didn't run yet.
scheduler.AdvanceBy(1);
```

Instead, you need to always start the task using `Observable.Start(task, scheduler)`, so the task runs in order:

```cs
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
AppContext.DefaultScheduler = scheduler;

Observable.Start(async () => {
    await TaskEx.Delay(100);
    Console.Write("Done");
}, scheduler);

/// this runs the code to schedule de delay
scheduler.AdvanceBy(1); 

/// this actually runs until the delay is complete
scheduler.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100).Ticks);
```

This is certainly trickier, so I wouldn't use it everywhere I use Task.Delay. But there are some specific pieces of code where the delay changes the behavior of the app and you need to test that, so it is useful for these special cases.

Comment: Thumbs up! This is by far the way to go since it allows tests to manipuate time.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by John Deters, this is an external dependency on the computers' clock (just as if you need to get the current time, although it's easy to call DateTime.UtcNow it is still a dependency).

However, these are special dependencies as you can provide a default that will always work (Task.Delay or DateTime.UtcNow). You can hence have a property to do this:

```
    private Func<int, Task> delayer = millisecondsDelay => Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay);
    public Func<int, Task> Delayer
    {
        get { return delayer; }
        set { delayer = value ?? (millisecondsDelay => Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay)) }
    }
```

Using this, you can replace the call to Task.Delay in your tests.

```
sut.Delayer = _ => Task.CompletedTask;
```

The clean way of doing this is, of course, to declare an interface and get it via your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider adding a timeout on your test and letting if fail if it has to wait for that long.

Or you could consider passing in the timeout, or a any way of configuring the timeout differently for tests.

There is a [blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-1-wrong-way.html) on async and TDD and another one [here](http://www.gamlor.info/wordpress/2010/11/c-5-0-async-feature-unit-testing-part-ii-synchronization-context-again/), though these more point out what can go wrong in general with async code rather than specifcally dealing with a `Task.Delay`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a test seam. It's simple, but not very clean. You may or may not to use this, depending on if you trust others not to mis-use it :-)

Add a public static property to your class

/// 
  /// delay, ony change for tests
  /// 
  public static int DelayMs { get; set; } = 1000;

In your code use it

```
await Task.Delay(DelayMs, cancellationToken);
```

In your unit test, change it to 0

```
MyClass.DelayMs = 0;
```